# multiple violin plots in one frame possible?

Tags: r

I am new to R. I created two violin plots from a .RData file. Is it possible to have both of them in one picture/frame instead of two separate?

I used in my example:

```
vioplot::vioplot(GER$K,las=2,main="GER$K",col="deepskyblue",notch=TRUE)
vioplot::vioplot(LIT$B,las=2,main="LIT$B",col="aquamarine",notch=TRUE)
```

thanks for your help. Jeff

Comment: I'd suggest converting your data to long format and using `ggplot2::ggplot()+geom_violin()`. Examples here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_violin.html

Comment: you can do that with a single call to vioplot `vioplot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))` or by using a list `vioplot(list(rnorm(10), rnorm(10)))` or by using the `add` and `at` arguments. these are covered in the examples of `?vioplot`, did you try those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Skaqqs suggested, an alternative is using `ggplot2`, which has great functionalities. The trade-off is that data needs to be in a specific format, called long.

I'm making an assumption that both `K` and `B` have the same units of measurement.

```r
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Create sample data
GER <- data.frame(id = 1:40,
                  K = rnorm(40, 15, 8))
LIT <- data.frame(id = 41:90,
                  B = rnorm(50, 24, 7))

# Join datasets and reshape them to a long format
dat <-
  full_join(GER, LIT) |>
  pivot_longer(c(K, B))

# Create the plot
dat |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_violin() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("deepskyblue", "aquamarine"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is by setting `add = TRUE`

```
vioplot::vioplot(GER$K,las=2,main="GER$K",col="deepskyblue",notch=TRUE)
vioplot::vioplot(LIT$B,las=2,main="LIT$B",col="aquamarine",notch=TRUE, add = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. If I do that, than I have one over each other. i would like to have them next to each other.

Comment: Then, par(mfrow = c(1,2)) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `par()`: it puts multiple graphs in a single plot by setting some graphical parameters: See help: `?par()`

Here is a fake example:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))   
p1 <- vioplot::vioplot(mtcars$mpg,las=2,main="mtcars$mpg",col="deepskyblue",notch=TRUE)
p2 <- vioplot::vioplot(mtcars$disp,las=2,main="mtcars$disp",col="aquamarine",notch=TRUE)
```

[image]